# Get current GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got a page with 3 GridViews.

```
<div id="Export" runat="server" class="headeropt noprint">

            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="buttonexport" OnClick="buttonexport_Click" OnClientClick="Javascript:Noshow();" CssClass="btn btn-default">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/Excel-16.gif" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Export" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
<div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CssClass="table" CellSpacing="0" OnRowDataBound="grid1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="grid1_RowEditing" datakeynames="grid1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("company") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="alinha-direita" />
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="alinha-direita" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:GridView ID="grid2" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CssClass="table" CellSpacing="0" OnRowDataBound="grid2_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="grid2_RowEditing" datakeynames="grid2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Family">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkprdfamily" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("prdfamily") %>' Text='<%# Eval("prdfamily") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="alinha-direita" />
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="alinha-direita" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="grid3" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CssClass="table" CellSpacing="0" OnRowDataBound="grid3_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowFooter="true" datakeynames="grid3">
            <Columns >
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

as you can see, the first grid links to the second, and the second to the third.
What I want to know, is at any given time to get the grid I'm viewing at the moment.

Just edited adding the linkButton that exports the grid to excel. This is why I need the gridview that I'm currently on, so that the export command works at any time.

Here's the export code:

```
protected void buttonexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs c)
{
    Master.Page.Form.Attributes.Remove("onsubmit");
    CB.ChangeControlsToValue(grid1);
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=File.xls";
    //Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    grid1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just edited the request.

Answer (score 0):

Nevemind, got a solution.

I've just checked the one that is visible at the moment and work with it.

```
bool list = grid1.Visible;
    if (list)
    { CB.ChangeControlsToValue(grid1); }
```

and so on....